# Comparator output stays high

Tags: analog, comparator

I am trying to figure out a strange behavior of comparator in the following schematic:
[image]
[image]

The idea is to process incoming signal (input range 0V - 12V) from jack J1 and via applying a small hysteresis and inverting produce a square signal with amplitude 0V - 5V labelled NF.
597SA3 is an old Latvian IC with the following internal schematic (note the integrated 10k resistor labelled R17 that is also present on my schematic):

[image]

The following is measured with my oscilloscope (yellow trace - input at pin 7 of comparator - swings from 0V to 12V at fixed frequency; blue trace - output at pin 11 of comparator - stays almost constantly 5V):

[image]

This is not the behavior that I expected.
Couple of observations:

- All the supplies (12V; 5V; GND; -12V) are stable and connected to the respective pins)
- Non-inverting input of comparator at pin 8 stays at ~ 6V as expected
- Resistance between 5V and pin 11 while device disconnected from supplies measures 10.6k which is expected value for integrated resistor

If anyone can provide a suggestion on why the output is prevented from being pulled low I would appreciate your help.

Comment: What levels does your input signal switch between relative to 0 volts?

Comment: @Andyaka input signal is external signal that is switching from 0V to 12V

Comment: P.S. if you know a little Python, it is easy to connect that 'scope to your network and remotely capture the screen; see [https://github.com/rdpoor/rigol-grab](https://github.com/rdpoor/rigol-grab).

Comment: The internal circuit does not look capable of accepting input voltages up to V+. During the edges of the input signal there is a very short time, where the input voltage passes a valid range above 6 V and this produces the negative output pulses. Use a sine wave or triangle input signal to see where the valid input range ends.

Comment: @Ivan That IC looks like it was designed when PNP was weak and hard to come by. I see just 3. I can't tell from the schematic and I don't want to presume anything right now: which rails tie to -V and to +V of the IC? Is it -12 V and +12 V?

Comment: @Ivan I've [re-drawn the differential part](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HkZib.png) of the schematic. (The output stage is not included.) It may help to see it this way. (For example, it may be easier to see that the sum of the currents in R6 and R9 should yield a constant emitter sink for VT11 and VT13.)

Comment: @periblepsis this IC dates back to at least middle 80s based on production dates I've seen. 12V and -12V are used as supplies, correct. Thank you, your schematic is much clearer!

Comment: @Jens thank you! I've tried using [sine-like](https://ibb.co/6vczgZV) and [scaled down square](https://ibb.co/qrc0sS7) inputs and they work as expected. Since my intended input will be 0V to 12V square I will try passing it trough resistor divider and adjust trigger point value.

Comment: @Ivan Are you good, now? Or are you looking for an appropriate circuit with hysteresis, still?

Comment: @periblepsis I think that yours and Jens's are sufficient - I will make the necessary adjustments to the circuit. Thank you!

Comment: @Ivan Sounds good! If any problems remain...